# Single code base application for android, iOS and web using Nativescript and Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing single code base application for android, iOS and Web using Nativescript and Angular example provided in the link https://jlooper.github.io/angular-starter/#creating-a-project , do we have enough support for this approach.

Is there any better alternative to develop for my requirement.

Comment: Hello, this repo has been deprecated, and its inspiration, Nathan Walker's Angular Advanced Seed, has also been de-promoted in favor of Team Maestro's simplified seed. I'd recommend reading the definitive guide on code sharing by Sebastian Witalec: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/code-sharing-between-web-and-mobile-with-angular-and-nativescript and reach out to Sebastian for help if needed. Thanks!